# Why don't Miracles occur in Kali Yuga?

Tags: kali-yuga, siddhi

Why are miracles not seen or don't occur in Kali Yuga?

I ask because:

- Each of the previous yugas have stories like Sages, Rishis, or Muni **cursing or giving Boon**.
- It is also said they possess magical powers and now there are **no magic or powers seen in daily life**.

Comment: Miracles occur in Kaliyuga, the most common place to find miracles is Tirupati, the lord's vigraha(moolavar) is miracle iself. 
Bhagwad Ramanujacharya witnessed one miracle when other sects were trying to capture Temple he saved Temple https://controversialhistory.blogspot.in/2011/07/is-tirupati-balaji-temple-buddist.html
http://www.tirumalesa.com/when-this-shockingly-amazing-miracle-occurred-inside-the-tirumala-temple/ 

http://allindiaroundup.com/india/in-pictures-11-shocking-facts-about-tirupati-balaji-temple-that-are-hard-to-believe/

Comment: Nice question 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per [oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/miracle), **Miracle** is 'an extraordinary and welcome event that is not explicable by natural or scientific laws and is therefore attributed to a divine agency'.

If we go by above definition, there are many such events happened in Kali Yuga too. Books by recent Yogis or Swamis narrate many such episodes. You also mentioned in your question, "now there are no magic or powers seen day to day". Such "magical powers" are possessed by few Yogis. I quote few incidents from books I read.

1. **Miracles performed by Neem Karoli Baba:**

[Neem karoli Baba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neem_Karoli_Baba) was ardent devotee of Lord Rama and used to chant Rama nama always. Here are some of his powers or miracles he preformed which are mentioned in Book, [Living with Himalayan Masters](http://www.amazon.in/Living-Himalayan-Masters-Rama-Swami/dp/0893891568) by Swami Rama.

> One day a pharmacist was delivering some powder from Talital to
> Malital. He was a devotee of Neem Karoli Baba, so he stopped to see
> him on the way. I was also there.
>
> Baba said, “I’m hungry. What is
> that you are carrying?” The pharmacist said, “This is arsenic. Wait
> and I will bring some food for you.” But Baba snatched the powder from
> him and ate a handful. Then he asked for a glass of water. The
> pharmacist thought he would die from the poison, but the next day he
> was quite normal.

He also ate continuously all day 40 times.

> One day I thought, “Let me see how many times he can eat.” That day he
> took forty meals at various houses. He was eating the whole day. We
> wanted to know about his powers, and he knew what we wanted. So when
> anyone brought food before him, he ate. They would ask, “Will you
> eat?” And he would say, “Okay.” He went on eating all day. Finally I
> came and said, “You have eaten enough.” He said, “Oh, have I?” I said,
> “Yes!” In such a high state one becomes like a child. He is not fully
> aware of mundane things, but he is constantly aware of the Truth.

Swami Rama lived in Himalayas meeting various Yogis with supernatural powers. He described many such miracles in his book "**Living with Himalayan Masters**".

2. **Giri Bala- Women Yogi who never eats**:

Paramahamsa Yoganada, in his famous book [Autobiography of Yogi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobiography_of_a_Yogi), mentions many miracles. One such miracle is about Giri Bala who never ate anything in her life.

> "Sir, we would like to know more of the fasting saint."
>
> "Her name is Giri Bala," I informed my companions. "I first heard
> about her years ago from a scholarly gentleman, Sthiti Lal Nundy. He
> often came to the Gurpar Road home to tutor my brother Bishnu."
>
> "'I know Giri Bala well,' Sthiti Babu told me. 'She employs a certain
> yoga technique which enables her to live without eating. I was her
> close neighbor in Nawabganj near Ichapur (in West Bengal). I made it a point to
> watch her closely; never did I find evidence that she was taking
> either food or drink. My interest finally mounted so high that I
> approached the Maharaja of Burdwan  and asked him to conduct an
> investigation. Astounded at the story, he invited her to his palace.
> She agreed to a test and lived for two months locked up in a small
> section of his home. Later she returned for a palace visit of twenty
> days; and then for a third test of fifteen days. The Maharaja himself
> told me that these three rigorous scrutinies had convinced him beyond
> doubt of her non-eating state.'

3. **Maheswaranath Babaji meeting Sarpa from Sarpa Loka**:

[Sri M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Madhukarnath) went to Himalayas to find his Guru [Mahavatar Babaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahavatar_Babaji) who taught him in his previous birth. He encounters Maheswaranth Babaji, direct disciple of Mahavatar Babaji in Uttarakhand. Madhukarnath also mentions many miracles in his book, [Apprenticed to Himalayan Master](https://www.amazon.in/Apprenticed-Himalayan-Master-Yogis-Autobiography-ebook/dp/B007F2I3F0). Here is one such incident.

> A strange spectacle unfolded before my astounded eyes. The rumbling
> had stopped and there was utter silence. The fireball, which was about
> two feet in diameter, split vertically into two, and out of it emerged
> something that caused goose pimples all over my body. It was a large
> snake, with a hood like a cobra, glowing electric blue, as if made of
> a transparent, violet, glass like material, with electric filaments
> lit inside. The snake-like creature’s eyes glowed, and it hissed
> softly.
>
> My fear vanished the moment I saw the creature bend down and
> touch Babaji’s feet with its hood. Babaji blessed it by touching its
> head with his right hand, and then did something, which for a second,
> made me wonder if what I was seeing was a silly dream, or reality. He
> hissed in reply. The blue cobra straightened up and sat facing Babaji.
> A hissing conversation went on for quite some time. Then Babaji said,
> “Madhu, come forward and see the deputy chief of the Sarpa Loka.” I
> moved forward and carefully sat behind Babaji. The snake hissed.
> Babaji said, “Bow down to Nagaraj.” I bowed low before the snake. At
> close quarters, I could see that he was quite big and had intelligent
> sparkling eyes. The snake hissed and touched my head with his forked
> tongue. I found that I was not the least bit frightened, although I
> could feel a mild electric shock passing through my body.
>
> Then
> abruptly, it slithered back into the globe, the two halves of which
> clicked shut, and with a rumbling sound, the globe took off and soon
> vanished in the clouds. I could not but ask Babaji to explain.
> “Babaji,” I said, “I deserve an explanation. If I said this to
> anybody, they would think I am utterly crazy, or that I am concocting
> some kind of fiction, so I shall keep this to myself. But please,
> explain to me.”

To this, Babaji says there was stellar system in Milkyway where Sarpa Loka exists. Nagas encountered with humas when people were evolved mentally through Yoga. He says when people became selfish Nagas stopped contacting with people of earth and went to NagaLoka.

Though these all appear as miracles, in reality they all can be explained by Yoga or by sastras (scriptures) derived from Vedas. Paramahamsa Yoganada explains science behind these miracles in **Chapter 30 "Laws of Miracles"** in his book **Autobiography of a Yogi**.

Apart from Miracles mentioned in books, they are also miracles happened very recently, such as  [strange Light caught](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psT_-i9NtQ4) before **Utsava Murthi of Venkateswara in Tirupati Brahmotsavams**. We may infer (from Chapter 30 of Autobiography of a Yogi) that light could be any Deva or creator Brahma in their Sookshma Sareera (Subtle body) who usually come there to perform *utsavam* (celebration) for Lord Venkateswara (Vishnu).

You can read above mentioned books to know more about miracles performed by various Yogis.

As a sidenote, Siddhis (supernatural powers)  acquired by Yoga shouldn't become obstacles in our quest to find the Ultimate truth (Brahman).

Answer (score 6):

First of all, miracles can only be performed by Gods and by beings who are enlightened like the powerful `Yogis`, `Siddhas`, `Mahamunis`, `Rishis` etc. We ordinary beings can't perform the miracles.

So, we need to see why Gods are not performing any miracles these days or where those enlightened Munis and Yogis are nowadays.

In Kali Yuga the atmosphere is overwhelmingly sinful. In Kali the PApa Purusha rules. Adharma rules over Dharma. In such situations Deva's beneficial powers get diminished.

For example, without proper Yajnas Gods gradually loose their power, If cows are slaughtered Gods loose their power too. So. that's why Gods don't probably show their miraculous powers. The sinful and impure state of Kali Yuga & their inhabitants prevent the Gods from producing miracles in this age like they used to do so often in the previous Yugas.

Gods need a pure plane to operate upon which they are possibly not getting in this age.

Now, its stated  in Puranas like the [Devi Bhagavatam](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam1.htm) and the Vayu Puranam that although the ill effects of Kali is very powerful but it can not reach a place called [Naimisharanya or the Naimish forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naimisha_Forest).

And that by the order of God all the Mahamunis, Rishis and Yogis take shelter in this forest until the next Satya Yuga arrives. It is by that way they save themselves from the sinful grasp of Kali.

So, since the enlightened beings, capable of performing the miraculous acts, take rest in a secluded forest in Kali, they don't interact with us. And, so even if they are performing some miracles we can't even have  a clue.

> S’aunaka said :– “O Sûta! What are those Purânas and how many verses
>   are contained in each? Speak all those in detail in this holy Ksettra;
>   we, the residents of Naimisâranya are all very eager to hear this.
>   (Why we call ourselves as the residents of Naimisâranya, hear; **you
>   will realise then that no other place exists in this Kali age for
>   hearing the holy discourses on religion) :– When we were afraid of the
>   Kali age, Brahmâ gave us a Manomaya Chakra (wheel) and I said to all
>   of us :– Follow this wheel, go after it and the spot where the felly
>   of the wheel will become thin (so as to break) and will not roll
>   further, that country is the holy place; Kali will never be able to
>   enter there; you all better remain there until the Satya age comes
>   back**. Thus, acording to the saying of Brahmâ, we have got orders to
>   stay here. On hearing the words of Brahmâ, wo went out quickly keeping
>   the wheel go on, our object being to determine which place is best and
>   holiest. When we came here, the felly of the wheel become thin and
>   shorn before my eyes; hence this Ksettra is called Naimis; it is the
>   most sanctifying place. **(Devi Bhagavatam, Book 1, Chapter 1)**.

IMHO, these are the reasons why we don't see too many miracles happening these days.

Answer (score 2):

Miracles happened in kali yuga too. the fact is we not believe them or clarify them right now. because it is kali yuga.

Did you hear about Sai Baba? Many educated people pray sai baba. 
Everyone who knows him says he is god.
he born in kali yuga only.

This section put light on current theory 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sai_Baba_of_Shirdi#Claimed_miracles

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! On this site answer's should be backed by citing sources from authentic Hindu scriptures.Pls.try to add some sources in your answer with examples of miracles from texts like puranas or books of life stories Guru's , achryas etc. .At this point your answer is just like a commemt.Visit the link to know more about writing good answer on this site -https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Sure i will make my answer much descriptive with examples.

Comment: Though wiki may be cited, you can cite Sai Sat Charitra which is available [here](http://www.saibaba.org/saisatc.html). You can update few sentences from it when you have time.

Comment: delete my comment. 
I will answer in the way I want to 
you can not force me to answer in your way.

Comment: @NaveenGiri It's not my way. Wiki is not a acceptable source on this site.

Comment: "removing his limbs or intestines" - what could be the purpose of such a "miracle?"

Answer (score 1):

Chaitanya Mahaprabhu was a spiritual leader and avatar of Lord Vishnu in kali yuga (next will be Lord Kalki).

From the historical records about Lord Chaitanya, we will get a picture of a God-conscious saint who appeared in India during the sixteenth century.

Chaitanya Mahaprabhu united in himself two aspects:
an ecstatic devotee of Krishna and Krishna himself in inseparable union with Radha.
According to the hagiographies of 16th-century authors, he exhibited his Universal Form identical to that of Krishna on a number of occasions, notably to Advaita Ācārya and Nityānanda Prabhu.

More - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_Mahaprabhu

Answer (score 1):

In modern day i.e. as of day today there are 100s if not 1000s of yogis and siddhas expressing these extra-ordinary powers. They are not known for the following reasons

1. Many of them live a recluse life
2. Systematic campaign to discredit them (for eg Puttaparthi Sai Baba)
3. Extreme apathy by scientific community in India in studying them (for eg there is a well-known yogi who can live without food, there was not deeper study done after initial study)

As of now Dyanapeetam has the largest collection of Yogis (100s) exhibiting Yogic Shaktis. 108 of them exhibited **Yogic Shakti** of ***blindfold reading***, which was certified by India Book Records on June 21, 2017 (International Yoga Day)

References:

1. https://therationalhindu.com/supernatural-powers-demonstration-world-record-created-by-hindu-gurukulam-kids-studying-under-858f62a2189e
2. http://indiabookofrecords.in/most-people-reading-blindfolded-together-at-single-venue/

Comment: To my knowledge there is no study which confirms yogi's can live without food. The yogi's who say that they can never wanted to cooperate in an investigation. I hope they will cooperate someday.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20110811094543/http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2010-07-17/ahmedabad/28293767_1_medical-team-leptin-claims

Comment: The study has not been submitted to any peer-reviewed journals. Moreover,
Jani gargled and bathed during the study. So is not hard to sneak some water in.
Urine was found to form in his bladder. Though it is claimed that he did not urinate.
Jani was allowed to move out of CCTV camera view, leave the room for sunbathing and receive devotees. It is easy for someone to have sneaked in food.
Rationalist Sanal Edamaruku claims to have been denied permission to check the test setup.