# Are there siddhas/yogis living today in Bharata ? Have any of you met one?

Tags: siddhi

Siddhas or Yogis are those who have gained super-human powers through meditation or tapas. The Ashta-Maha siddhis detail some of these. But there are other 'smaller' siddhis as well.
e.g. in Ramakrishna Kathamrita, they mention a Pavhri baba who subsists only on air.

Have any of you met such a person while traveling in India ?

What powers did they exhibit ?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17941/3500).