# Why is the supernatural so hard to find in the modern day? Why does Atheism exist?

Tags: philosophy, science, supernatural-races, supernatural

Why is the supernatural so hard to find in the modern-day? Is there a conspiracy to keep it hidden? Why would a group do such a thing? Why do Atheists exist?

While there is a lot of compelling evidence for the supernatural for many people, that leads to the question of why the supernatural is so hard to find. Shouldn't you run into it on a daily basis if there is no reason not to? Especially with how many supernatural entities are in Hinduism.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124704/discussion-on-question-by-aupakarana-abhibhaa-why-is-the-supernatural-so-hard-to).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Miracles do not occur in Kali Yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17930/why-miracles-do-not-occur-in-kali-yuga)